# The parametric equations of a straight line passing between two points

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given $A=(2,5,1)$ and $B=(3,0,3)$, what are the parametric equations of a straight line passing between $A$ and $B$?

My attempt:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=2+t \\ 
y=5-5t \\ 
z=1+2t
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

and

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=3-t \\ 
y=5t \\ 
z=3-2t
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Comment: Although both are correct, it might be more important to describe how you arrived at them.

Comment: There is an infinite number of such equations. How did you happen to choose these two as *the* equations?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's correct they are both right!

The first is the equation from A to B $$\vec {OA}+t\vec {AB}$$

and the second is the equation from B to A $$\vec {OB}+t\vec {BA}$$